# Visa Requirements for Belarus for EU citizen

Tags: visas, eu-citizens, ukraine, belarus

I am doing a journey from Romania to Estonia and I'm currently in Ukraine (Kiev).
I messed up and did not realize that I needed a visa for Belarus until I got here. Tomorrow I am planning to go to the embassy and apply for an expedite one.

They require, together with the basic stuff, the following information:

- Either visa for the next country (in my case Lithuania) or itinerary (with bookings)

Since I am from the EU, I don't need a visa for Lithuania, but I obviously cannot be booking transportation and place to stay if I am not 100% sure I will get a visa (you never know).

What can I do?

Comment: Could you link to that visa requirements page? To make sure it's the ones for EU citizens. Also could you just get refundable bookings to construct an itinerary?

Comment: The one I found was for EU citizens. Yeah, I am thinking of building an itinerary but the hardest part (and most expensive) is the transportation to/from Belarus. The accommodation can be done via hostelworld or something.

Comment: Have you tried simply bypassing Belarus?

Answer (score 4):

I am from Germany and am staying in Minsk for a little more than one month right know. For my Visa I needed

- to pay 60€,
- present a health insurance,
- have an invitation to Belarus,
- submit a photograph,
- have a passport that is valid through the whole time of my stay.
- Also I needed to register within 3 workdays of my arrival here.

If you do not want to stay I am pretty sure, for a transit visa, there are no such requirements. But you may have to present some proof that you will travel further, like a flight ticket or a visa of the country you are travelling to.

Comment: I went there and required a health insurance which *clearly stated* its validity in Belarus. I had 2 but they didn't state it, so out of luck.

Comment: I had a similar problem, @N3sh, but when I spoke to my travel insurers, they'd encountered the situation before and knew what to do. They posted me an official-looking certificate (at no cost) confirming that my existing insurance policy covered Belarus and was valid for the duration of my stay.

Answer (score 2):

You would Need to book the tickets before applying for the visa I'm afraid - the exception is where tickets **cannot** be booked in advance (which is not the case here since you're already in Ukraine), in which case you should explain it to the embassy in an explanation letter containing your itinerary, which the embassy may or may not accept.

The good news is, if you give them the required docs, in all likelihood you'll have no problems getting it. Russian and Belarusian transit visas are easy to get for EU citizens.

You don't need to show any hotel bookings for a transit visa, only the Transport tickets

Your only other option is going via Poland rather than Belarus